# Virtual HDD of an Ubuntu 14.04 VM gets read-only

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, virtualbox, hard-drive, read-only

I work with VirtualBox. The host system is Windows 7m the guest -- Ubuntu 14.04.

Some time ago I extended the HDD of the VM from `10` to `20` GB. Don't know, if it relates to the issue, but it was the last significant change in the last time. (After it I also upgraded MySQL from `v5.5` to `5.6`, but I don't think, it has any relevance now.)

The issue is, that now the VM hard disk over and over again gets read-only. I can use the VM some short time (maybe about one hour), but then it falls into the read-only mode. On rebooting I get this screen:

[image]

> Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.
>
> Press F to attempt to fix the errors, I to ignore, S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery...

Pressing `F` doesn't really help and after `I` I get the next error:

> Unable to set up logging. [Errno 30] read-only file system '/var/log/landscape/sysinfo.log'

[image: errno 30]

After this it's not possible anymore to start the machine:

[image: VirtualBox error message]

> An error has occurred during virtual machine execution! The error details are shown below. You may try to correct the error and resume the virtual machine execution.
>
> The I/O cache encountered an error while updating data in medium "ahci-0-0" (rc=VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER). Make sure there is enough free space on the disk and that the disk is working properly. Operation can be resumed afterwards.
>
> Error ID: BLKCACHE_IOERR
>
> Severity: Non-Fatal Error

I reset it to the last snapshot:

[image: snapshots]

Then I can again use it for a short time period until the issue occurs again.

What can be the cause and how to get the issue fixed?

Comment: This question doesn't belong here, since it is not a problem with Ubuntu. Ask in the [virtualbox forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/).

Comment: I wasn't sure, on witch side the issue actually is, so I decided to ask it here, at a probably wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a specific Ubuntu question but here are some things you can try:

1. Check if your host has enough disk space free (at least to support what you have allocated)
2. Enable the host cache I/O if not enabled already(Storage>SATA controller)

If these don't help you out, check out the Virtualbox forum and check if there are any existing tickets raised regarding this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it out with enabled cache for the SATA Controller, but it didn't help. And to the disk space: Yes, on the the host it's definitely enough free space. And on the guest I extended the VDI from 10 to 20GB, so it should the also not be a problem.

Comment: Resizing the VDI is not enough to increase allocation to the guest OS. The guest OS (Ubuntu) will detect this new space as unallocated until you format this new space to EXT4.

Comment: It's a misunderstanding: Sure, I've added the new free space to the main (ext4) partition (with GParted).